# Display None and Block based on h1 text string

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="usr-box">
<h1 id="usr-type">dc_vendor</h1>
</div>
```

In above code h1 tag can return two values "dc_vendor" & "whole-seller". I want to display: block the total div when the h1 value is "whole-seller" and display: none; when h1 value is "dc_vendor" using jQuery. I am pretty new in JQuery. Kindly help me please

Comment: why Jqery whan you can simply use javascript? `if(document.getElementById("usr-type")=="dc_vendor") document.getElementById("usr-box").style.display = "none";`

Comment: You'll need to update your question with some jQuery code for what you've tried.  SO is not a site for code requests (people here won't write code for you).  Please review [the details on how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Then we'll be happy to help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make the default display:block, then add this in your script

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
  if($('#usr-type').val()=='dc_vendor').css({'display':'none'})
})
```